# django getting kwargs value in template

Tags: python, django, templates

Lets say I have a function where I am passing template:

```
def somefunc(template, **kwargs):
    body = render_to_string(tempate, {"kwargs":kwargs})
```

In my template I want to access this kwargs value:

```
Hellooww {{kwargs['username'}}, welcome to the site...
```

But I am not getting this username. Can it be done this way?

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

You could use via **view.kwargs** for access to kwargs accessible in View:

[image]

Comment: this is correct. you have to access using {{ view.kwargs.your_variablename  }} from a template used by a class view.

Answer (score 3):

Django templates have a different type of lookup, to access `username` on the dict `kwargs` you should use `{{ kwargs.username }}`.

For further explaination take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/api/#variables-and-lookups).

Comment: in django 2.1 (not sure about other version)
{{ view.kwargs.username }}

Answer (score 2):

To perform lookups on dictionary in a Django template, you need to **use the `.` (dot) notation**.

> Dots have a special meaning in template rendering. A dot in a variable
>   name signifies a lookup.

When the template system encounters a dot `.` in a variable name, it tries the following lookups, in this order:

1. **Dictionary lookup**. Example: foo["bar"]
2. **Attribute lookup**. Example: foo.bar
3. **List-index lookup**. Example: foo[bar]

So in your case, you just need to do:

```
{{ kwargs.username }}
```

The template system on encountering the `.` in the variable `kwargs.username` will perform a dictionary lookup on the dictionary `kwargs` by the key `username`.